# Excel: Formula that supports more than 15 digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

My formula is follows:

```
{=TRUNC(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A600,FIND(" ",A1:A600)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A600,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},0)*3),0))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A600,FIND(" ",A1:A600)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A600,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},0)*3),0)))-1)/3)*3)),2)&" "&INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},INT((LEN(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A600,FIND(" ",A1:A600)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A600,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},0)*3),0)))-1)/3))}
```

Everything works perfectly to the "PB"

"EB" give result: 1024000000000000 MB

"ZB" give result: 1024000000000000000 MB

"YB" give result: 1.024E+21 MB

"BB" give result: 1.024E+24 MB

I guess the problem arises because it has more than 15 digits numbers. How to force excel to show me all the measuring units correctly.

I use Excel 2016

Comment: Better share some Sample data with us to test and fix the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I get this a lot too. I think it's just a format issue. Select your column and change the drop-down format from "general" to "number". Then just make sure your column is wide enough to display all the characters.

Just noticed you also have "MB" at the end... In this case may want to try "text" format to force it to show as is and not perform any post-calculations on the result of your formula

Comment: My task is to calculate the consumption for internet data in a few years back where the result >"EB" I tried format cell to "TEXT" but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

MrK is absolutely right , here is the formula with "text" formula

```
=TEXT(TRUNC(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A600,FIND(" ",A1:A600)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A600,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},0)*3),0))/(10^(INT((LEN(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A600,FIND(" ",A1:A600)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A600,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},0)*3),0)))-1)/3)*3)),2),"0")&" "&INDEX({"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},INT((LEN(SUM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A600,FIND(" ",A1:A600)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A600,2),{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB","BB"},0)*3),0)))-1)/3))
```

Comment: I just tried the formula now. Not work for me.

Comment: try it without curly braces

Comment: without curly braces result is 0 KB